# How can I override ForeignKey readonly field? Force delete an attribute?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of python objects mixed with Django model instances and need to overload the `__eq__` operator on some of the fields for filtering. This works fine until I run into a `ForeignKey` which throws an error due to the attribute only accepting the specific model instance.

How can I override this attribute? Even deleting it would be nice as I have no use for it in the template.

The reason for this pattern is that under certain conditions, I'd like certain attributes to always match the incoming search parameters on a per object basis (I have wildcards in the objects being searched, not the search query).

```
class AlwaysEqual(object):
    def __eq__(self, a):
        return True

for i in bag_of_objects:
   if certain_conditions_met:
       i.foo = AlwaysEqual()
       # ValueError: Cannot assign "AlwaysEqual": "ProductFile.option1" must be a "ProductOptionValue" instance.
       # is there a way to delete this attribute?

       del i.foo
       # AttributeError: __delete__
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a non-model instance in this case? Just create a dummy model instance with overriden **eq** method:

```
class MyDjangoModel(models.Model):
    match_always = False

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        if (self.match_always):
            return True
        return self.id == obj.id

    .....

always_equal = MyDjangoModel()
always_equal.match_always = True


for i in bag_of_objects:
    if certain_conditions_met:
        i.foo = always_equal
```

Comment: cool idea! I like it. I'd be curious how to override the attribute itself though... It's strange having a property I can't change.

Comment: Why do you want to override it? I'm not quite sure to understand the purpose of this override... Can you give some example?

Comment: it doesn't really matter why I want to override it: this is an academic question. The `SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` has a `__set__` throwing this error. How can I remove the attribute itself. How do I reset an attribute?

Comment: In other words, how do I remove `fk_field` from an `instance`, should I ever wish to?

Comment: You are breaking the model this way... there are plenty of ways to modify model values, but deleting a field is probably the worst one...

Comment: I agree. Your method is fantastic, and I am very appreciative of it. I'm still wondering how one can delete an attribute when prevented in this fashion. I'm used to being able to override *anything* in python. Do you understand why I'm asking this question? I'm not saying it's a good idea  in my particular application. I'm curious how it can be done.

Comment: According to the source code - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L222 it checks if the value is None - have you tried to delete the field after setting it to None value? Maybe it is possible to delete it, you just have to clear lots of references in the code...